# form_for: undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, null, form-for

Things have been working fine, but I've just updated the gems via `bundle update` and now my `/register` page is showing an error:

> **NoMethodError in Users#new_signup**
> undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass

[image]

The error is on the `form_for` line in the view.
This is the `users_controller`'s action:

```
def new_signup
  @user = User.new
  @user.practice = Practice.new
  render :layout => 'login'
end
```

Here's the view `new_signup.html.erb`:

```
<h1>Sign Up</h1>
<%= form_for @user, url: '/register' do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

For clarify, `new_signup` action in the `users_controller` routes to the `/register` url in `routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'register', to: 'users#new_signup', as: 'register'
  post 'register', to: 'users#create_signup'
  ...
end
```

**Is something wrong with any of this? What could I even debug?** I've tried changing *form_for* to `form_for User.new url: '/register' do |f|` doesn't help.

I've done an `abort @user.inspect` which returns an empty hash of all the fields in my model..which seems like that's what it *should* output.

Here's the output from the `bundle update`:

```
$ bundle update
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Resolving dependencies...
Installing rake 10.4.2 (was 10.3.2)
Installing i18n 0.7.0 (was 0.6.11)
Installing json 1.8.2 (was 1.8.1)
Installing minitest 5.5.1 (was 5.4.2)
Using thread_safe 0.3.4
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using activesupport 4.1.1
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using actionview 4.1.1
Using rack 1.5.2
Installing rack-test 0.6.3 (was 0.6.2)
Using actionpack 4.1.1
Using mime-types 1.25.1
Using polyglot 0.3.5
Using treetop 1.4.15
Using mail 2.5.4
Using actionmailer 4.1.1
Using activemodel 4.1.1
Using arel 5.0.1.20140414130214
Using activerecord 4.1.1
Using encryptor 1.3.0
Using attr_encrypted 1.3.3
Installing bcrypt 3.1.9 (was 3.1.7)
Using bundler 1.7.3
Using chronic 0.10.2
Using coffee-script-source 1.8.0
Installing execjs 2.2.2 (was 2.2.1)
Using coffee-script 2.3.0
Using thor 0.19.1
Using railties 4.1.1
Using coffee-rails 4.0.1
Installing hashie 3.3.2 (was 3.3.1)
Using hike 1.2.3
Using multi_json 1.10.1
Installing jbuilder 2.2.6 (was 2.2.1)
Using jquery-rails 3.1.2
Installing pg 0.18.1 (was 0.17.1)
Using tilt 1.4.1
Installing sprockets 2.12.3 (was 2.11.0)
Installing sprockets-rails 2.2.2 (was 2.1.4)
Using rails 4.1.1
Installing rdoc 4.2.0 (was 4.1.2)
Using sass 3.2.19
Installing sass-rails 4.0.5 (was 4.0.3)
Installing valuable 0.9.9 (was 0.9.8)
Installing schema_plus 1.8.4 (was 1.6.0)
Using sdoc 0.4.1
Installing spring 1.2.0 (was 1.1.3)
Installing turbolinks 2.5.3 (was 2.4.0)
Installing uglifier 2.7.0 (was 2.5.3)
Using whenever 0.9.4
Updating files in vendor/cache
  * rake-10.4.2.gem
  * i18n-0.7.0.gem
  * json-1.8.2.gem
  * minitest-5.5.1.gem
  * rack-test-0.6.3.gem
  * bcrypt-3.1.9.gem
  * execjs-2.2.2.gem
  * hashie-3.3.2.gem
  * jbuilder-2.2.6.gem
  * pg-0.18.1.gem
  * sprockets-2.12.3.gem
  * sprockets-rails-2.2.2.gem
  * rdoc-4.2.0.gem
  * sass-rails-4.0.5.gem
  * valuable-0.9.9.gem
  * schema_plus-1.8.4.gem
  * spring-1.2.0.gem
  * turbolinks-2.5.3.gem
  * uglifier-2.7.0.gem
Removing outdated .gem files from vendor/cache
  * spring-1.1.3.gem
  * uglifier-2.5.3.gem
  * json-1.8.1.gem
  * rake-10.3.2.gem
  * schema_plus-1.6.0.gem
  * pg-0.17.1.gem
  * rack-test-0.6.2.gem
  * sass-rails-4.0.3.gem
  * turbolinks-2.4.0.gem
  * execjs-2.2.1.gem
  * bcrypt-3.1.7.gem
  * hashie-3.3.1.gem
  * i18n-0.6.11.gem
  * rdoc-4.1.2.gem
  * minitest-5.4.2.gem
  * valuable-0.9.8.gem
  * jbuilder-2.2.1.gem
  * sprockets-2.11.0.gem
  * sprockets-rails-2.1.4.gem
Your bundle is updated!
```

**Update 1:**

I've followed [Jay's process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28060781/426935) below to try to create a User via the console. That has worked fine, but this error via the URL persists.

**Update 2:**

Still no luck. I've installed Better Errors and I'm looking through the Full Stack Trace. The error appears to be in the `form_for` helper as it's trying to instantiate the form for the User class, which it doesn't think has a `new` method.

Since the `@user` instance variable is already a new instance of a User, doesn't it make sense that it doesn't have a `new` method?

I've dumped the trace into JSFiddle (obviously the links aren't then clickable, so I've created a fiddle for the top 3 items of the Full Trace):

- form_helper#instantiate_builder: http://jsfiddle.net/tz4he49d/embedded/result/
- ## form_for: http://jsfiddle.net/Lu2fd6u0/embedded/result/
- Users#new_signup: http://jsfiddle.net/z217ueqj/embedded/result/ (image shown below)

[image]

Comment: You need to get your story straight: *now my /register page is showing an error:*  Yet, you say the error is on another page, i.e new_signup.html.erb, which just so happens submits to /register.  Just post the FULLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL error message.

Comment: @7stud I've added the `routes.rb` for clarity. The `new_signup` routes *to* the `/register` url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was due to my `gemfile` settings.

Rails was "locked" to version **4.1.1** whereas other gems were free to update to whatever version they wanted.

Updating my gemfile so the Rails version used is **4.1.9** and restarting the app has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Turgs,

Your code looks good, and it should be a red flag that it was working before, and not after updating your Gemfile.lock.  Your error suggests the User ActiveRecord object is in question.

Things I would do:

1.) Kill your local server and restart it.  Sometimes things get weird; start fresh.

2.) Check your schema.rb.  Does it have the all the tables and columns you are expecting?

3.) Open `rails c` and type User.  Do you get the fields it corresponds to with in your schema.rb?  If not, you need to start a connection with your database.

4.) Try creating a User.  Use the bang method User.create!(required_attributes_here)  This will give a good traceback.  I would expect it to fail.

5.) What database are you using?  Check your database in your console to make sure the db name matches what you have in your database.yml file.

6.) If you can, do a rake db:yolo; Ie. rake db:drop, rake db:create, rake db:migrate, rake db:seed (last is optional).

Hopefully this can give you further clues/solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks Jay. Very helpful process! Steps 1-3 didn't help. Step 4 proved I **can** successfully create a User via the console. Now I'm really stumped.

Comment: Update: I've followed all steps. (1) done this lots without change. (2) all looks fine.  (3) looks fine too. (4) surprisingly the User did create (5) Postgres. Everything I can see between DB and yml config looks good (6) done db:reset lots too. Unfortunately... still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, it is all about form_for helper.
Try setting the url as a path, explicitly, e.g.:

```
<%= form_for @user, url: signup_path, html: { method: :post } do |f| %>
```

and edit routes.rb:

```
post 'register', to: 'users#create_signup', as: 'signup'
```

Hope it helps.

Does the error occur when you just try to load the /register page or when you submit it?